# Summing up values from certain column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple dataGridView with 4 columns. I want to sum up values from a third column and save the result into variable on button press. I tried like this, but I always get an error saying

> "Specified cast is not valid - when casting from a number, the value must be less than infinity".

P.S. Each cell is bassically a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, meaning I can input values directly.

Code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Double result = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            result += (Double)row.Cells[2].Value;
        }

        this.label13.Text = result .ToString();
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than casting, try

```
result += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[2].Value);
```

With error checking

```
if (row.Cells[2].Value != null)
{
    try
    {
        result += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[2].Value);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt =DataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

decimal total;

total=(int)dt.Compute("sum(column_name)","");
```

Comment: this will fail if `column_name` only has `null` values due to `invalid cast specification`

Answer (score 0):

```
private getColSum()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    }
    return sum;
}
```